# How to specify a size range for consecutive NAN's i.e ignore NAN's that are only one element long?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, user-defined-functions, nan, missing-data

I'm trying to find consecutive NAN's in a set of data and fill in the missing NAN's with it's closest known data point without interfering with the NAN's I've already filled in.
So far the code I've written for the function is:

```
function [max_x, min_x] = missing(x)

max_x = x(:, 2);
min_x = x(:, 3);

for jj = 1:length(max_x)
    for kk = 1:length(min_x)
        if isnan (max_x(jj))
            max_x (jj) = ((max_x(jj-1)+max_x(jj+1))/2);
        elseif isnan (min_x(kk))
            min_x (kk) = ((min_x(kk-1)+min_x(kk+1))/2);
        elseif isnan (max_x(jj)>1)
            max_x = fillmissing (max_x,'nearest');
        end
    end
end
```

This fills in the single NAN's.  How do I fill in the other missing consecutive NAN's?

Comment: So if you have `[ 1 nan 2 nan nan 3 nan 4 nan nan 5]` you want that to become `[ 1 nan 2 nan 3 3 nan 4 nan 5 5]`?

Comment: If you had `[1 nan nan nan 2 ]` what would that become? how about  `[1 nan nan nan nan 2 ]`?

Comment: So if I had [1 nan nan nan nan 2 3 nan nan 3 nan nan nan nan 4], i want it to become [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4]

Comment: What about `[ 1 nan 2 nan nan 3 nan 4 nan nan 5]`

Comment: I would want that to become [ 1 1.5 2 2 3 3 3.5 4 4 5 5 ]

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
x = [ nan 1 nan 2 nan nan 3 nan 4 nan nan 5 nan ];

% Handle outer nan's special way, just first & last not nan's
in = find(isnan(x));
nnF = find(~isnan(x), 1, 'first');
nnL = find(~isnan(x), 1, 'last');

x( in( in < nnF ) ) = x( nnF );
x( in( in > nnL ) ) = x( nnL );

% Now handle inner nan's
in = find(isnan(x));
nn = find(~isnan(x));

% Find close low & high neighbors
low = interp1( nn , nn , in , 'previous' );
high = interp1( nn , nn , in , 'next' );

% Is it closer to low, high, or equal from both
closerToLow  = in - low <  high - in;
equidistance = in - low == high - in;
closerToHigh = in - low >  high - in;

% Perform transform
x(in(closerToLow)) = x(low(closerToLow));
x(in(equidistance)) = (x(low(equidistance)) + x(high(equidistance)))/2;
x(in(closerToHigh)) = x(high(closerToHigh));
```